# NSolve produces large coefficients in Roots[...] result

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics

I'm attempting to plot a function's derivative approximation but encountering numerical errors. The issue seems to stem from NSolve generating large coefficients. I'm unsure how to fix it. Any advice would be helpful.

Using NSolve with a simple function:

```
f = -9.053811245162477 + 9.053901162548637 (1 + dx) (1 + dy) + 
   17.68915226070889 ((1 + dx) (1 + dy))^(1/3) + 
   9 ((1 + dx) (1 + dy))^(5/3) + 
   0.12149758669595068 ((1 + dx) (1 + dy))^(1/3) (3 + dx + dy) + 
   2.9999702059749005 (-3 ((1 + dx) (1 + dy))^(2/3) - 
      6.018 ((1 + dx) (1 + dy))^(4/3));
```

Attempting to solve this equation with NSolve:

```
solution = NSolve[f == 0, dx, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

This results in solutions with extremely large numbers:
$1.56416\times 10^{139}+3.70384\times 10^{144} \text{dy}+$

Modifying f coefficients slightly results in even larger numbers, reaching up to 10^150.

Judging from plots of $f$ it is a well behaved function.

I need to plot dxdy defined as following:

```
dxdy = Simplify[ dx / dy /. solution [[1]]]
```

expecting it would behave relativelly well, too, but getting strange numerical error near 0:

```
Plot[{dxdy}, {dy, 0, 1}]
```

[image: dxdy]

Comment: **NSolve[f == 0, dx, with high numerical precision]** Could you post the actual code you used?

Comment: @Nasser updated

Comment: **need to plot dxdy** you also did not show the plot command you used. I get different plot. But I do not know what you typed to generate the plot you showed. It is always better to show code of what you did.

Comment: @Nasser thank you very much! I got function f in a buffer from different notebook and occasionally pasted it :(

Now, I copied everything right, and then creating notebook by coping from my post it creates a plot I have in the picture.

Comment: At zero you have: $-\infty$ try: `solution = dx /. Solve[Rationalize[f, 0] == 0, dx, Reals]; Limit[
 solution[[1]]/dy, dy -> 0, Direction -> -1]` ?

Comment: When you suspect precision issues, use exact values. `fPrec = f // Rationalize[#, 0] &; solutionPrec = Solve[fPrec == 0, dx, Reals];` You will get the same curve.